# Open source solution to capture and decrypt SSH traffic (with private key)?

Tags: cryptography, public-key-infrastructure, ssh, ids

I am looking for a free open source solution that is able to capture and decrypt SSH traffic given the fact that I can provide the server's RSA private key (something like SSH CryptoAuditor).

Please advise.

Answer (score 4):

[mitmssh](http://www.signedness.org/tools/) is the only tool I'm aware of capable of MITM'ing SSHv2 sessions.  If you're looking for after-the-fact capture decode, that's not possible, as SSH universally uses ephemeral key exchange mechanisms.